# Does gliclazide increase occurrences of reactive hypoglycemia

Tags: hypoglycemia, type-2-diabetes

I've recently been prescribed a minimal dosage of Gliclazide (40 milligrams a day).  I've been diagnosed type 2 diabetic for two years and until I was on the Gliclazide I'd never even come close to a hypo.  Since I've been on it I've had 4 hypos.  Today I had one, even though I'd eaten a lot of sugar (Had a bag of sweets shortly after lunchtime).

At about 6 pm I had another hypo.  My wife read up on various things and told me about reactive hypoglycemia, and I was wondering if that's the likely cause of my hypo today.  My eating habits haven't changed much in the last 12 months (I'm generally a good diabetic, with the odd naughty day, like today), but I was wondering if the Gliclazide could have made reactive hypos more likely?